# Request for a proof that $\sum\limits_{i=1}^n i^{k+1}=(n+1)\sum\limits_{i=1}^n i^k-\sum\limits_{p=1}^n\sum\limits_{i=1}^p i^k$

Tags: sequences-and-series, proof-verification, summation, induction, alternative-proof

> Prove 
>   $$\sum_{i=1}^n i^{k+1}=(n+1)\sum_{i=1}^n i^k-\sum_{p=1}^n\sum_{i=1}^p i^k \tag1$$
>   for every integer $k\ge0$.

By principle of induction,

$$\sum_{i=1}^n i = n(n+1)- \sum_{p=1}^n p$$
$$2\sum_{i=1}^n i = n(n+1)$$
$$\sum_{i=1}^n i = \frac{n(n+1)}{2}$$
$\implies$$(1)$ is true for k equals to zero.

Assume $(1)$ is true.
$$\sum_{i=1}^n i^{k+2}=(n+1)\sum_{i=1}^n i^{k+1}-\sum_{p=1}^n\sum_{i=1}^p i^{k+1}\tag2$$
We prove $(2)$ is true.

From $(2)$,

$$\begin{align}
RHS & = (n+1)\left[(n+1)\sum_{i=1}^n i^k-\sum_{p=1}^n\sum_{i=1}^p i^k \right]-\sum_{p=1}^n\sum_{i=1}^p i^{k+1}\\
& = (n+1)^2\sum_{p=1}^n p^k-(n+1)\sum_{p=1}^n\sum_{i=1}^p i^k-\sum_{p=1}^n\sum_{i=1}^p i^{k+1}\\
& = \sum_{p=1}^n\left[(n+1)^2p^k-(n+1)\sum_{i=1}^p i^k-\sum_{i=1}^p i^{k+1}\right]\\
& = \sum_{p=1}^n\left[(n+1)^2p^k-\sum_{i=1}^p (n+1+i)i^k\right]\\
\end{align}$$

By examining $(2)$,

$$\sum_{p=1}^n\left[(n+1)^2p^k-\sum_{i=1}^p (n+1+i)i^k\right]=\sum_{p=1}^n p^{k+2}=LHS\tag3$$

We should be able to get $(3)$.

Anyone knows how to prove $(3)$?

Comment: You could start with $$\sum_{p=1}^n\sum_{i=1}^p i^k=\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{p=i}^n i^k=\sum_{i=1}^n(n+1-i)\, i^k.$$

Answer (score 1):

Rather than proceed using induction, I thought it might be instructive to present a straightforward approach.

To that end we proceed by using the [Newton Series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summation_by_parts#Newton_series) for summation by parts with $f_i=i$ and $g_i=i^k$.

Then, we can write

$$\begin{align}
\sum_{i=1}^n i^{k+1}&=\sum_{i=1}^n (i)(i)^k\\\\
&=n\sum_{i=1}^n i^k - \sum_{j=1}^{n-1}\sum_{i=1}^j i^k\\\\
&=n\sum_{i=1}^n i^k - \sum_{j=1}^{n}\sum_{i=1}^j i^k +\sum_{i=1}^n i^k\\\\
&=(n+1)\sum_{i=1}^n i^k - \sum_{j=1}^{n}\sum_{i=1}^j i^k
\end{align}$$

as was to be shown!

Answer (score 0):

You can also simply reverse the order of summation in the double sum:

$$\begin{align*}
(n+1)\sum_{i=1}^ni^k-\sum_{p=1}^n\sum_{i=1}^pi^k&=(n+1)\sum_{i=1}^ni^k-\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{p=i}^ni^k\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^n(n+1)i^k-\sum_{i=1}^n(n-i+1)i^k\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^n\big((n+1)-(n+1-i)\big)i^k\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^ni\cdot i^k\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^ni^{k+1}
\end{align*}$$

Answer (score 0):

In the RHS, a term $j^k$ is taken $n+1$ times in the first sum and $n-j+1$ times in the second, hence it contributes $(n+1-n+j-1)j^k=j^{k+1}$ to the total.

---

$$\left|\begin{matrix}
1\cdot1^k\\
2\cdot2^k\\
3\cdot3^k\\
4\cdot4^k
\end{matrix}\right|=\left|\begin{matrix}
1^k&1^k&1^k&1^k&1^k\\
2^k&2^k&2^k&2^k&2^k\\
3^k&3^k&3^k&3^k&3^k\\
4^k&4^k&4^k&4^k&4^k
\end{matrix}\right|-\left|\begin{matrix}
1^k&1^k&1^k&1^k\\
2^k&2^k&2^k\\
3^k&3^k\\
4^k
\end{matrix}\right|$$